# Why am I getting results containing Re and Conjugate?

Tags: matrix, vector

Using the matrix `Ham4LVLReg1`, I am trying to get four vectors. Initially, I got the eigenvectors, and then, I computed the eigenvectors `E1` and `E2` orthonormal to each other. When I continued with the rest of my calculations after this point, there seems to be a major problem. I noticed that, when I output `λ2`, there are still terms such as "Conjugate" and "Re"; how can I make this evaluation proper?

Note: I do not think `λ2` needs to be normalized. Orthogonalization should do that).

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
Ham4LVLReg1 = 
  {
    {0, 0, 0, Ωa1[t]},
    {0, 0, 0, Ωb1[t]},
    {0, 0, 0, Ωc1[t]},
    {Ωa1[t], Ωb1[t], Ωc1[t], 2 Δ}
  }/2;

Evecs = Eigenvectors[Ham4LVLReg1];
E1 = Eigenvectors[Ham4LVLReg1][[1]];
E2 = Eigenvectors[Ham4LVLReg1][[2]];

λ1 = E1/Sqrt[E1.E1];
λ2a = Orthogonalize[{E1, E2}][[2]];
λ2 = λ2a/Sqrt[λ2a.λ2a];
```

Comment: Mathematica by default assumes that variables are complex valued, which is why you're seeing conjugates and such in your output. You can simply the result with `FullSimplify` if you specify which variables are real valued in the assumptions.

Comment: Have you tried using `ComplexExpand` ? This will assume all terms are real and expand out simple expressions. However, Mathematic assumes that complex solutions are possible from square root and trig calculations. They may happen for special cases of your variables, perhaps cases which are not interesting for you.

Comment: ComplexExpand worked - thank you !!!!!